# Как достать текст из файла .txt присланного пользователем боту Telegram? (библиотека telebot)

Tags: python, telebot

Пользователь присылает файл .txt. Нужно достать оттуда текст и сохранить в строку, предварительно проверив что файл формата .txt

Я написал хендлер для получения файла, но никак не могу достать оттуда текст и не знаю как сделать проверку на тип файла.

Библиотека telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
    def get_new_credentials(message):
        file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохраняем присланный от пользователя файл:

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
def handle_file(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
        src = 'C:/Python/Project/bot/files/received/' + message.document.file_name;
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, e)
    log(message)
```

Для проверки расширения файла:

```py
if 'txt' == message.document.file_name.split('.')[1]:
    return True
```